# Is it possible to keep the socket.io open even when the app is closed

Tags: ios, react-native, socket.io

I am learning the ways to build a Chat app for iOS and Android using React Native and Socket.io. At the point, the socket is always connected to the server when the app is on foreground. The problem here now is when the app is manually closed by the user, the socket disconnects and never comes alive until the User switches it back.

After a research on it I came out with `Headless js` which acts as a service but unfortunately it only works on Android and not iOS.

Is there any idea as to how to work this around to make the `socket open` even when the user closes the app? I would be grateful to know.

Comment: what would be the point of that? Can't you just resume it when the app comes back into the foreground?

Comment: @ADyson It means when the app is closed the User will not receive messages from the socket. But I would like the user to receive messages from the socket even when the app is closed

Comment: Again, what would be the point of that, when the app is closed / suspended? Not like the user can see them. You can re-open the socket when the app re-starts and collect any messages not yet received by the app. Or maybe you should be using push notifications or something - it's hard to tell based on your description. Either way it kind of sounds like the solution to the wrong problem

Comment: @ADyson I saw a question unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/q/48054982/2595059 maybe it can give you more insight to what I am asking

Comment: Not sure why that's any different to your question really. Why can't you use push notifications like every other app in the world?

Comment: @ADyson Working with Socket.io, you can only use local notifications when socket.io receives messages. But in my situation the Socket.io is disconnected when the app closes.

Comment: So then you probably need another means to send push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions to handle this problem is using the package `react-native-background-task`.
But this has some limitations, you can't schedule a periodic task more frequent than 15 minutes.
If the iOS user closes the app manually, the task will not run.

the other alternatives are:
`react-native-background-timer`, `react-native-background-fetch`, `react-native-background-geolocation`.

It depends on your use, but iOS internally has limited capabilities for closed state of the app.